Games sometimes crash and reset my PC/GPU
CPU: Ryzen 9 5900x
GPU: Radeon RX 6700XT
Often when playing games on steam they will freeze and my pc will completely restart. It closes everything and brings me back to the login screen. i did sudo journalctl -b -1 -e for the most recent crash after seeing it on a related issue here and it gave the following:
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: src/common/pipes.cpp (883) : fatal stalled cross-thread pipe (pipe is disconnected).
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: src/common/pipes.cpp (883) : Fatal assert; application exiting
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: 12/09 16:28:19 Init: Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)/tid(17130)
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
                                                            /tmp/dumps/assert_20241209162819_8.dmp
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop steam[4653]: /tmp/dumps/assert_20241209162819_8.dmp
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop whoopsie[23738]: [16:28:19] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Dec 09 16:28:19 desktop systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop steam[4653]: assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop steam[4653]: assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: response: Discarded=1
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop steam[4653]: assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20241209162819_8.dmp'', upload yes: ''Discarded=1''
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: response: Discarded=1
Dec 09 16:28:20 desktop assert_20241209162819_8.dmp[23762]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20241209162819_8.dmp'', upload yes: ''Discarded=1''
Dec 09 16:28:26 desktop kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma1 timeout, signaled seq=182554, emitted seq=182556
Dec 09 16:28:26 desktop kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
Dec 09 16:28:26 desktop kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
Dec 09 16:28:26 desktop kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to disallow df cstate
Dec 09 16:28:26 desktop systemd[1]: Started whoopsie.service - crash report submission.
Dec 09 16:28:27 desktop whoopsie[23788]: [16:28:27] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Dec 09 16:28:27 desktop systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.

from the looks of this it almost seems like the game crashes, then my gpu resets itself after an error, but im not entirely sure. im very new to linux and cant really read all of this.
my GPU is pretty new, less than a year old. but i have encountered some hardware issues such as a malfunctioning DP port. I never had crashes happen like this on Windows, however, which makes me wonder if it could be software related. any help is appreciated.

which OS are you running?

im running 24.04.1 LTS

please update your question... a comment is not the place for it ... add olit right at the beginning of your post
